# Cannot import name 'BlockBlobService'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I got the following error:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService 
ImportError: cannot import name 'BlockBlobService'
```

when trying to run my python project using command prompt.  (The code seems to work when i execute it directly from anaconda navigator.)

I am using  Python 3.6.4 for Anaconda. Running `pip freeze` gives me the following:

```
azure-nspkg==2.0.0   
azure-storage-blob==1.1.0
azure-storage-common==1.1.0 
azure-storage-nspkg==3.0.0
azurepython3==1.7.7
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import Azure BlobService in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35558463/how-to-import-azure-blobservice-in-python)

Comment: Not the same issue .

Answer (score 13):

There is no need to install the entire `azure` package.

I believe you are using the new `azure-storage-blob` library, but since `BlockBlobService` is from the old `azure-storage` library, to continue using it, you need to `pip uninstall azure-storage-blob` if you have installed the new library by accident, and then `pip install azure-storage` to install the old library.

If you would like to use the new library or cannot do the above, feel free to refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58900508/5305519) which details the context and full instructions of using either the new `azure-storage-blob` library or the old `azure-storage` library.

Comment: This is the message received when trying to install `azure-storage` in order to use `BlockBlobService` "Starting with v0.37.0, the 'azure-storage' meta-package is deprecated and cannot be installed anymore.
    Please install the service specific packages prefixed by `azure` needed for your application."  Even using `pip install azure-storage==0.36.0` results in `----> 8 from azure.storage import BlockBlobService

ImportError: cannot import name 'BlockBlobService' from 'azure.storage' (unknown location)`